# Obtener cookies de la respuesta de encabezados en ionic 3

Tags: angular4, ionic3, http-post

Estoy trabajando en iónico 3 y necesito obtener la respuesta de las cookies de los encabezados. miren eso:

```
Set-Cookie:.AspNet.TwoFactorCookie=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie:.AspNet.ExternalCookie=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie:.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=-mi7oCB299B3rTFplCLZoY-M46grmtB5G6QY90Z8636uUTIQVWhZzmyTKZRzt2fTPGqHqrV409f5SiDa44qsuZPCqqp5rOAshKx6WBi-p2oDQx9CqFphRez9wfrFtwYHAaNZrSv3EtlzmUKgsAx6WzZ-bbADmc1MKrWoK9iWN_oOlR-LoJQURSzF1zk29P5puMQb_osco5FSA9NBSbsiEfqWT-FaY5sDclgiBVPrDu6aw5KOtrKh50pEKH5coneroHW_Qnv_Eizso8F2sTmgK0wuC4Feq-iu5kmkA-3f59j59KwbFir6bHt2rJYLrA-kXR3U28AXd9TszN_K39p_WgyNywYl8UyC_OA56Wu5rVAfiUmN76CyAE_MqGZit1Kap43Db1IzCv-Hif8AgTbyVxni8tcaucvaXXwssrvv2YnEhSZRupywRMu7539W-MK5e5pDKRM2ImZLsFnDMOpbJDeCSkNPFsfqAyybgbSp79lX4OVh98yiN-xkRMkbp_IRBiD1UFpTJF81seD1fcn_Sg; path=/; expires=Sun, 11-Mar-2018 05:16:12 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:ARRAffinity=1c9f49441daef96a3a5b64bf3c3bd25480d9a2c738819ed568ce423efddd7076;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=tarjetadsalud-mobile.azurewebsites.net
```

esos son los headers response al loguearme, necedito obtener la cookie para enviar en cada peticion el token de session
Aqui mi codigo

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    that.http.post('htttp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     JSON.stringify(params), {
                        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

                      }
                      )
                      .subscribe(res => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(resolve(res)));


                        if(res['Resultado'] == true){



                            localStorage.setItem('Username',res['Nombre']);
                            navi.setRoot("HomePage");
                        }else{
                            that.toastCtrl.presentToast('Usuario o Contraseña incorrecta');
                        }




                      }, (err) => {
                          alert('Error de usuario o contraseña')
                        reject(err);
                      });
                  });
```

de antemano gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto [tour], puede 
tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link [ask], es posible que su pregunta sea 
cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal para mas información vea 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions . Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, no entiendo por qué envuelve un observable en una promesa, es totalmente innecesario.

Comment: disculpa, soy nuevo en el asunto. podrias explicarme la diferencia por favor, un observable y una promesa